# Python3.10.4 serial readline() not displaying prompts

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, pyserial, readline

Right now, I am connecting to a device using Tera Term and manually running over 50 tests. My goal is to automate these tests. Currently I am trying to do this through python using the pyserial library. The issue I am running into is readline() will display everything until the login prompt appears. It stops on the line before.

What it should look like

```
Booting: 2022.08
CPU:     cpu_id
In:      serial
OUT:     serial
Normal Boot
Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0

Starting Kernel ...

Enter your credentials
cpu_id login:
```

what readline() is displaying:

```
Booting: 2022.08
CPU:     cpu_id
In:      serial
OUT:     serial
Normal Boot
Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0

Starting Kernel ...

Enter your credentials
```

Here is the code I am currently playing with:

[image]

Any insight would help. Or, if you know of another way to run tests through a serial port, I'm all ears.Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `ser.flush()` after each `ser.write` call to ensure it blocks until all data is finished writing?

Comment: Also, you `break` *before* you `sleep` or `write` anything, so that's a major red flag there. Presumably you meant to actually perform the `sleep`/`write`, *then* `break`? `break`ing first means you never actually `sleep` or `write`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are correct but that was intentional. I wanted to see if we would even see the login prompt before attempting to write to it. The problem is not with the write but with the readline(). It stops reading right before the login prompt. Its like readline() is incapable of reading prompts. I edited the code to make it less confusing.

Comment: If the prompt doesn't end in a newline (intentionally, with the idea that the user would respond on the same line), presumably `.readline()` won't pick it up? Seems like the `readline` call would probably be blocking waiting for the newline.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. With what you said in mind. I broke the loop early, logged in blind, then started reading again and this seemed to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @ShadowRanger I was able find a work around. I ended the readline() loop the line before the login prompt. I then logged in and ran a test blind then started reading again afterwards. Here is the code I used:

[image]

This is not the cleanest code but it explains the process well enough.